# meta tag is not working for ipad to zoom out full width of website

Tags: ipad, zooming, viewport, meta

I am working on a website: [www.sc1.online-folio.com](http://www.sc1.online-folio.com)
for mobile and tablet devices I want to show this site 100 zoomed out (or maybe a little more) so user can see full site at first glance and zoom in the area he wants to view.

I am using this meta tag to zoom out

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1100" initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
```

I set the width 1100 so the website look a little zoomed out for better viewing of slider area. This is all working fine on android devices but on ipad and iphone the site is zoomed like this: http://www.responsimulator.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fsc1.online-folio.com%2F and no changes in meta properties are working.

So guys can you tell me what exactly I do to control the zooming on iphone and ipad devices.

Answer (score 1):

You have written the attribute incorrectly, replace the quote after width with a comma.

So that:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1100" initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
```

Becomes:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1100, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
```

But to answer your question, viewport is the thing!